I keep getting import statement error when running tensorflow example
I am new to tensorflow and trying to get some examples to work from this book by OReilly "Learning Tensorflow.js" and I have installed node, and run the tensorflow install script npm install @tensorflow/tfjs
and when I run a simple example to check the version using these two lines:
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

console.log(tf.version.tfjs);

I get this error in the console:
'Cannot use import statement outside a module'

I don't understand what the issue is because these files came right from the book download site.

Modify your package.json to include:
{
  "type": "module"
}


I don't have a JSON file. The instructions in the book did not say to create one or that I needed one.

@MichaelFlorant Use npm init to create one.
